# Weight lifting gloves with straps between fingers

Tags: weightlifting, gloves

I recently purchased some (different to my usual) weight lifting gloves with extra padding on the palm, really for doing tricep dips on bars. Between the fingers are some straps, so the first two fingers are connected, as are the last two. My question is... why? I've seen this on some other gloves but I don't understand how it would help with anything. The straps just get in the way.

Comment: I've always understood that it's meant to prevent injury caused by the fingers being spread out forcefully. Although I've never come across the need for this. On another note... If you can avoid using gloves, you should avoid using gloves. They tend to give you an easier time with your grip, but your grip *should* be trained in order to not lag behind.

Comment: Ditch the gloves and use chalk. I have no idea who lied to who and started the weight lifting glove thing.

Comment: For me, I use padded gloves because the bar, with weight, presses into my palms and after a short while it is uncomfortable (especially if the bar is narrow). Chalk would work for the other reasons I use them - losing grip from sweat etc.

Comment: It will continue to be uncomfortable until you do it for a little while and get used to it (just like almost everything you do in the gym). You'll develop a better grip without the gloves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, they are used to get the gloves off since that's pretty hard otherwise, at least that's what I used them for when I did use gloves.

As others have said, ditch the gloves, they don't help with grip strength, since they effectively increase the diameter of anything you're going to grab, larger diameter - harder to grip.

They also don't really help against calluses since you don't get the same precision in where you are grabbing as you would bare handed.

Comment: OH THAT KIND OF STRAPS, yea they are used to pull the freaking gloves off. I even have those gloves(never used them tho, just got for free) For some reason, i thought about that finger taping...